# Clock widgets in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, date, time

I need to show system date in my web site through wordpress in PHP.
it shows system time one time but not updating as days gone passed.
I need to change it according to my system date

Comment: PHP is executed on the server.  Once your server executes the PHP script, it just returns the HTML to the client.  The client will need to refresh and have the PHP executed again on the server and return an updated HTML page.  What you want to do is use javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can't show your system time using PHP. If you want to show your system time you just need to use javascript.

try this,

```
  var currentTime = new Date()
  var hours = currentTime.getHours()
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

  var suffix = "AM";
  if (hours >= 12) {
  suffix = "PM";
  hours = hours - 12;
  }
  if (hours == 0) {
  hours = 12;
  }

  if (minutes < 10)
  minutes = "0" + minutes

  document.write("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix + "</b>")
```

***Update:***

If you want to show everything, please try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.write(new Date());
</script>
```

Comment: thanks Ramesh its really working but all i need to do is to show calendar there. that means i date, month and a year to show up...